# I am unable to hit WebMessageReceived event using callback function from web page using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, webview, webview2

I am working on an application where I need to call a WebMessageReceived event of WebView2 from the web page deployed but it is not working. below is the code for WebView2 and Front_End application.

```
Private Async Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Try
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

                Await wvGravityPayment.EnsureCoreWebView2Async
                Dim url = String.Format("https://ba63-203-215-162-154.ngrok-free.app/?transactionToken={0}", mTransactionToken)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(url) Then
                    wvGravityPayment.CoreWebView2.Navigate(url)
                End If

                AddHandler wvGravityPayment.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf wvGravityPayment_WebMessageReceived

            Catch ex As Exception
                ShowException(My.Resources.MsgCantPopulateForm, ex)
            Finally
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Sub wvGravityPayment_WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs) Handles wvGravityPayment.WebMessageReceived
            Dim jsonData As String = e.WebMessageAsJson()
        End Sub
```

> Javascript Code

```
<script>

    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.id = 'cip-hosted-urlpage';
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.classList.add("iframeStyles");
    $("#iframeDiv").append(iframe);

    window.onload = function() {
        // set up event listener on Pay With Card button
        function StartTransaction () {
            //e.preventDefault();
            // get a transactionToken serverside
            //getToken().then(function (transactionToken) {
                //initialize the emergepay url library.
        var transToken = getUrlVars()["transactionToken"];
        debugger
                var urlPage = emergepayUrlPage.init({
                
                    // (optional) Callback function that gets called after a successful transaction
                    onTransactionSuccess: function (approvalData) {
                        console.log("Approval Data", approvalData);
                        postCallbackResponse("true", approvalData);
                        //$(".iframeContainer").hide();
                    },
                    // (optional) Callback function that gets called after a failure occurs during the transaction (such as a declined card)
                    onTransactionFailure: function (failureData) {
                        console.log("Failure Data", failureData);
                        postCallbackResponse("false", failureData);
                    }
                });
                                // set the source of the iframe to the emergepay page.
        
                iframe.src = urlPage.getUrl(transToken);
                iframe.style.display = 'block';
                $(".iframeContainer").show();
            //});
        }
        
        // Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
        function getUrlVars()
        {
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
            {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
        }
        
        // Post response message from Callback function
        function postCallbackResponse(approved, callbackResponse)
        {
            window.chrome.webview.postMessage(JSON.parse({isApproved: approved, transactionResponse: callbackResponse}));
        }
        
        StartTransaction();
    }
</script>
```